# How to avoid using a var when doing multiple string replacements in a string

Tags: scala

This is what I tried:

```
def doStringReplcements(originalStr: String, replacementsMap: Map[String,String]): String = {
  var newStr = originalStr
  replacementsMap.foreach { pair => 
     newStr = newStr.replaceAllLiterally(pair._1, pair._2)
  }
  newStr
}
```

But functional programming style recommends avoiding vars so how do I do this with just vals?

Comment: Your code doesn't work, functional or not? `replaceAllLiterally` returns the new string, it doesn't change `newStr`. `newStr = newStr.replaceAllLiterally` is needed...

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul was a typo, fixed, thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using the `foldLeft` function on Map.

e.g.

```
replacementsMap.foldLeft(originalStr){ case (accumulator, (target, replacement)) => 
    accumulator.replaceAllLiterally(target, replacement)      
}
```

Comment: This has two disadvantages, making multiple passes over the text, and also performing replacements on previous replacements: "ab" -> "Ab" then "Ab" is eligible for match, even though not in the original text.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a regex:

```
scala> import util.matching.Regex
import util.matching.Regex

scala> val text = "one in hand, two in bush"
text: String = one in hand, two in bush

scala> val reps = Map("one"->"lots","two"->"more")
reps: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(one -> lots, two -> more)

scala> val r = reps.keys.mkString("|").r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = one|two

scala> r.replaceAllIn(text, m=>reps(m.matched))
res0: String = lots in hand, more in bush
```